# will <b class="hidden-sm"> also hide if the screen is xs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got confused on how does boostrap works , for example let say i have the following Div:-

```
<b class="hidden-sm">Your cart:</b>
```

so this will hide the Div is the screen is small , but does this effect also applied is the screen is extra small `-xs`

Second question is i have this Div:-

```
<b class="visible-sm">cart:</b>
```

this means that the div will be displayed when the screen is small, but will it be visible when the screen is large ?

can anyone adivce please, what is the rule governing this ?

Comment: Why don't you try it :-) http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: @DanFromGermany i can try this ,, but i am asking about the rule that govern this..

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: the best answer is to simply read the documentation for specific your question: [#responsive-utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities), it cannot be explained better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will.

Simply put, the governing rules are:

- if you say `hidden-*`, then it will be hidden at only that device width.
- if you say `visible-*`, it will be visible at only that device width.
- you must use multiple device indicators (xs, sm, md, lg) if you want it to apply to more than one.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to read the source code to know how Twitter Bootstrap really works. In this case, that would be the CSS file `bootstrap.css` (JavaScript is irrelevant here). It contains:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .hidden-sm {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

This is the only thing where the class `hidden-sm` matters: it simply removes the element from the display if the viewport width is 768...991 pixels. So it does not affect “extra small” viewports. To cover them as well, you would need to code

```
<b class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Your cart:</b>
```

Classes like `visible-sm` are more complicated. For them, the code first sets `display: none` and then for a selected `@media` restriction `display: block`. Thus, similarly to the above, to cover “extra small” too, you would need to use

```
class="visible-sm visible-xs"
```

But there is the additional problem that when elements in such classes are visible, they are displayed as blocks, due to the CSS technique used. This means that if you have, say, `xxx <b class="visible-sm visible-xs">yyy</b> zzz`, then this will appear as “xxx zzz” when the viewport is large, but as “xxx”, “yyy”, and “zzz” each on a line of its own (and “yyy” in bold) if it is “small” or “extra small”.

These classes are meant to be used for blocks, typically for `div` elements, rather than inline markup such as `b` or `span`.

Comment: so i can say that visible and hide can either return true or false, depends on the  screen size only? for example visible-sm will check if the screen is small and will display the markup , but if the screen is xs or large , then the visible-sm will return false and will not display the markup ???

Comment: @johnG, the effect depends on *viewport width*. Classes are not true or false; instead, an element that belongs to a class like `visible-sm` may have some CSS rules applied to it due to the class, and here it means that the element is dropped out unless the viewport width is in a certain range. This indeed means that it is not displayed if that width is in the “extra small” range, unless the element *also* belongs to the `visible-xs` class.

Comment: but i mean the default implementation will work as i mentioned (true , false) is this correct?

Comment: pointing someone to read the source code for a [well documented](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) use case is redundant.

Comment: @HenryW, actually you need to read the source code to see that the logic works according to *viewport width*, not device width (even though the documentation says “device”).